# Issue in Running imported Macros in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, automation

I want to import macro files from the specified location in all the workbooks in specified folders and want to run macros over each workbook, I am able to import it in all workbooks successfully through the code mentioned below but can not able to run those macros.

```
Sub RecursiveFolders()
    Dim FileSys As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objSubFolder As Object
    Dim objFile1 As Scripting.File
    Dim wkbOpen As Workbook
    Dim szImportPath As String
    Dim objFSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim cmpComponents As VBIDE.VBComponents

    Set objFSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set FileSys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFolder = FileSys.GetFolder("C:\Users\Yashika Vaish\Desktop\testform")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.SubFolders
        For Each objFile In objSubFolder.Files

            Set wkbOpen = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=objFile)
            szImportPath = FolderWithVBAProjectFiles & "C:\Macros"
            Set cmpComponents = wkbOpen.VBProject.VBComponents

            For Each objFile1 In objFSO.GetFolder(szImportPath).Files

                If (objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile1.Name) = "cls") Or _
                   (objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile1.Name) = "frm") Or _
                   (objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile1.Name) = "bas") Then
                    cmpComponents.Import objFile1.Path
                End If
            Next objFile1

            Application.DisplayAlerts = False

            MsgBox "Import is ready"
            Application.Run "HeaderChange_User_Financial_Input"
            Application.Run HeaderChange_User_Financial_Input
            Application.Run HeaderChange_User_Operation_Input
            Application.Run SelectRangeUnitMap
            Application.Run reportingunitmap
            Application.Run HeaderChange_Finacial_Standard
            Application.Run HeaderChange_Operation_Standard
            wkbOpen.Close savechanges:=True
        Next
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

This Code gives me pop up that can't run macros,

> It may not be available or all the macros are disabled

But there is no password and protection so why I am not able to run macros, Kindly help.

Comment: Do you have the Macro Security settings set too high?  In `Excel 2010` - `File` ~ `Options` ~ `Trust Center` ~ `Trust Center Settings` ~ `Macro Settings` ~ make sure _Disable all macros without notification_ isn't set.  I'd generally advise to have _Disable all macros with notification_ set.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the workbook name when calling the macro (not tested):

```
strFile = ActiveWorkbook
Application.Run "'" & strFile.Name & "'!HeaderChange_User_Financial_Input"
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't use `Option Explicit` you didn't see your issue, therefore I recommend always to use `Option Explicit` to flag this sort of thing in future in the editor.

The issue here is that in

```
Application.Run HeaderChange_User_Financial_Input
```

VBA assumes that `HeaderChange_User_Financial_Input` is a **variable**  containing a macro reference. But this variable is empty because it is never set and therefore it can't find that macro.

I assume you meant `HeaderChange_User_Financial_Input` to be the macro name instead of a variable so use a string instead

```
Application.Run "HeaderChange_User_Financial_Input"
```

for all `Application.Run` in your code.